# Why doesn't this test work for my map function as written?

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming

I am asked to create a test for my map function below.

```
static <U,V> List<V> map(Iterable<U> l, Function<U,V> f) {
    List<V> hashes = new ArrayList<>();

    for(U x : l) {
        V y = f.apply(x);
        hashes.add(y);
    }

    return hashes;
}
```

The test I wrote takes a List of Strings and creates a List of Hashes that compares the mapped hashes to hashes of the api hashCode() function.

```
@Test
    public void testMap() {
        List<String> names = List.of("Mary", "Isla", "Sam");
        List<Integer> hashes = fp.map(names, hashCode());
        List<Integer> hashesComp = new ArrayList<>(); 

        for (String name : names) {
            int hash = name.hashCode();
            hashesComp.add(hash);
        }

        Assertions.assertEquals(hashesComp, hashes);
    }
```

This portion (in Eclipse)

```
List<Integer> hashes = fp.map(names, hashCode());
```

gives me an error:

```
The method map(Iterable<U>, 
 Function<U,V>) in the type fp is 
 not applicable for the arguments 
 (List<String>, int
```

What am I doing wrong? Isn't List an iterable and generics should take in the types I'm using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `map` method's second argument should be a `Function`. The expression `hashCode()` does not result in a `Function`; it calls the `hashCode` method which returns an `int`. Hence your error is that `int` is not assignable to `Function`.

I think you want to call `map` with a function that computes the hashCode of each string. The simplest way to do that is by passing a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to `String::hashCode`:

```java
List<Integer> hashes = fp.map(names, String::hashCode);
```